# Simulation data vs measure data

Tags: time-series, modeling, simulation, trend, climate

I am comparing climate simulation data (in reanalysis mode) to in situ measured data (from a weather station).

For now, the main variable I study is snow height (in cm).

Here is an exert of my data (to simplify, I aggregated my data on a monthly time step and only showed a year):

| Date | Measured | Simulated |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-06 | 249.329 | 159.015 |
| 2022-05 | 302.309 | 201.762 |
| 2022-04 | 357.936 | 226.027 |
| 2022-03 | 379.96 | 230.937 |
| 2022-02 | 405.719 | 202.505 |
| 2022-01 | 369.34 | 148.04 |
| 2021-12 | 320 | 103.75 |

I have already done R2, RMSE and Mean absolute error test:

| R2 | RMSE | MEA |
| --- | --- | --- |
| -10.4441 | 165.1862 | 157.6509 |

In sum, my simulation data tend to overly underestimate the amount of snow on the ground, which is not surprising. However, I would like to use said simulation data from 1982 to 2022 to explain change in patterns, I also have in situ data from 2006 to 2022.

[image: Graph of measured and simulated snow height]

Before using the simulation data to explain change in patterns, what would be a good way to test if the trends are the same between the two data sets ?